# Error: Could not issue a Let's Encrypt SSL/TLS certificate for website demovpstest.com

Tags: plesk, lets-encrypt

I have a Linux VPS with Plesk control panel. Today, I have added one domain name [demovpstest.com] on my Linux VPS through the Plesk panel. When I am going to enable Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate for my website, I am receiving the following error.

```
Error: Could not issue a Let's Encrypt SSL/TLS certificate for demovpstest.com.
Details
Invalid response from https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/68205530/1263660043

Details:
Type: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:malformed
Status: 404
Detail: No order for ID 1263660043
```

I've tried 2 - 3 times, but it failed. Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a BUG than will be solved by Plesk, meanwhile this worked for me:

1-Connect to the Plesk server via SSH

2-Search for the JSON file which contains the Let's Encrypt order in the /usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/orders folder:

```
egrep -Ril example.com /usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/orders
/usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/orders/c92788fed3b07d20e4ad823731285d30f0c88dcb.json
```

Note: replace the example.com with the name of the affected domain.

3-Remove the JSON file retrieved with the previous command:

```
rm /usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/orders/c92788fed3b07d20e4ad823731285d30f0c88dcb.json
```

4-Reissue the Let's Encrypt certificate